# Why didn't Chirrut Îmwe exhibit the talent he supposedly taught others?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, chirrut-imwe

Chirrut Îmwe is introduced in Rogue One as the last Guardian of the Whills.  The [Ancient Order of the Whills](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Order_of_the_Whills) taught Qui-Gon Jinn (and, thus indirectly taught Obi-Wan) the secret to remaining a Force Ghost after death.  Chirrut, the last Guardian, shows extreme skill and precognition consistent with Force sensitivity.  However, when

> he dies his body does not disappear; indeed, despite him telling Baze that he would be with him, through the Force, it appears that the last Guardian of the Whills lacks the one ability his group was known for.

Is there any known explanation for this inconsistency?

Comment: qui-gon didnt fade away though did he? maybe obi learned more tricks

Comment: @Himarm Honestly I've yet to read the full explanation for Qui-Gon. Some sort of post-death learning? At any rate, with Chirrut's constant prayer, it was really depressing that he didn't become one with the Force.

Comment: This is a joke question, isn't it.

Comment: @Werrf I wish it were.

Comment: Qui-Gon's body did not fade and he did not appear as a Force ghost because his training was incomplete at the time of his death.

Comment: @Axelrod He *did* become one with the Force. Coming back as a Force Ghost is different, everyone becomes one with the Force when they die.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Chirrut didn't become a Force Ghost because Disney Canon doesn't include that aspect of the Whills.

The former background of Qui-Gon being taught how to become a Force Ghost after death [was established in the Revenge of the Sith screenplay and Art book](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Order_of_the_Whills), pre-Disney canon.

As of the Disney's taking over the Star Wars universe, episodes of The Clone Wars (which is canon) have shown [this role in immortality training to be given to Force Priestesses, instead.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Priestesses)

Essentially, Chirrut's order is no longer tied to that aspect of Force lore, so he has no reason to turn into a Force Ghost. That aspect of awesome has been retconned out of existence.

Comment: What if Chirrut was not force-sensitive enough to become a Force Ghost or even a Jedi? Or what if even if he was sensitive enough, he was simply not trained on how to become a Force Ghost?

Comment: @RichS He was clearly good enough to become a Jedi, from what we're shown in the movie... not sure if blindness might have played a part in that not happening.  He also might not have been alive when they were around. At any rate, in current canon he wasn't trained on how to become a Force Ghost because an entirely different group teaches that now.

Answer (score -1):

Chirrut was not "Force-sensitive" - that is, he could not use or control the Force reliably. Given his age, he almost certainly would have been recruited by the Jedi if he had any noteworthy Force abilities, and would have been caught up in Order 66.

From the novelisation of Rogue One:

> "Who are they?"
>
> "The **Guardians** of the Whills. Protectors of the Temple of the Kyber. But there's nothing left to protect, so now they're just causing trouble for everyone."

The closest we get to a direct statement of his Force sensitivity comes a little later:

> "Is he Jedi?" he asked, with the hushed doubt of a man on the verge of a great discovery.
> ...
> "No Jedi any more. Only dreamers like this fool."

So if Chirrut isn't a Force user, how do we explain his preternatural dodging skills? Well, *Catalyst* made it clear that people who cannot use the Force can still *feel* the Force:

So I think we've got enough information to clearly answer the question.

Chirrut was not a Whill. He was certainly not a Shaman of the Whills. Chirrut was a member of a group called the Guardians of the Whills; this group guarded and protected the Temple of the Kyber on Jedha. Those who guard a group do not themselves have to be members of the group; Royal Guards aren't royalty, after all. While Chirrut could not control the Force himself, he did have the same slight sensitivity to it that all living things have. In his blindness, he learned how to use that sensitivity, and learned to trust it and trust his instincts.

He had no peculiar access to the Force, not the way Jedi and Sith do; but he has learned to make the most of the minimal access that he does have.

(I chose to delete my old answer which was clearly inadequate, and replace it with a new, clearer one).

Answer (score -2):

I did not know the background of this characte, but during his death scene, I thought it was implied enough that he had become a ghost and joined with his friend in the force.

Comment: When someone becomes a Force Ghost, their bodies disappear.

Comment: Hello. Don't forget to check out our [tour], and if you're planning on asking any questions, check out [ask] too!

Comment: @Terriblefan Not true! Qui-Gon's body did not disappear. There are several questions about Force Ghosts and bodily disappearance. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148538/was-obi-wan-the-first-jedi-or-first-person-to-transform-bodily-into-a-force-gh

Comment: @RichS Qui-Gon didn't know how to become a Force Ghost at his time of death... and no one bothered to check if his ashes disappeared later. ;)

Comment: @Terriblefan Check if his ashes disappeared? Has anybody ever seen Jedi ashes disappear?

Comment: @RichS Technically Obi-Wan should have been burned by the lightsaber. So maybe.